# Android Studio: ActionBarActivity becomes deprecated when adding a dependency?

Tags: android, dependencies, deprecated, android-actionbaractivity, floating-action-button

I'm somewhat of a newbie so do excuse me if this is really basic. Anyway, in an attempt to add a Floating Action Button (FAB) to my layout, I decided to add a dependency to a library, like this:

```
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
     compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2
}
```

But it seems that regardless of which library I choose, the same problem persists: ActionBarActivity gets crossed out and gives a warning saying it has been "deprecated".

Another issue is that I can't seem to use the "ImageView" type and must instead use "TintImageView". What does it mean for ActionBarActivity to be deprecated and how is this problematic? But most importantly, how do I fix it?

I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0 and this library: https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu

I would really appreciate any help, even if you're not sure or if the answer is incomplete.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to used `ActionBarActivity` or `Activity`.

`Theme.Material` is only available on devices running API 21 (Lollipop) and up. If you wish to use the Material theme on devices running API 20 and below, you need to use AppCompat.

> When I created a new activity, it extends ActionBarActivity but it's deprecated.

This is a very recent change. As of version 22.1 of AppCompat, `ActionBarActivity` has been deprecated in favor of [`AppCompatActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is because you are using the ActionBarActivity.
Try to change ActionBarActivity to Activity